# I am trying to do the following in LWC but it is not working for me, does anyone know what I can do?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to get the name and other fields from the Contact using the recordId

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Contact" icon-name="standard:contact">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={contact.data}>
                    <p>{name}</p>
            </template>
            <template if:true={contact.error}>
                {contact.error}
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
// Imports
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from "lwc";
// UI imports
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
// Schema imports (import others that you need
import NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name";

const FIELDS = [NAME];

export default class Test2 extends LightningElement {
  // Public properties
  @api recordId;

  // Wire functions
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", FIELDS })
  contact;

  get name() {
    return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, NAME_FIELD);
  }
}
```

META.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", FIELDS })
```

Should be:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS })
```

Note that JavaScript is case sensitive; the parameter name must be `fields`, not any other variation.

Comment: it shows me the following message: Action.prototype.finishAction Error  [Error in $A.getCallback() [NAME is not defined]
Callback failed: serviceComponent://flexipage.editor.aura.component.FlexipageComponentController/ACTION$loadComponentDefinitions]

Comment: your import is `NAME_FIELD` not `NAME`. So it should be `const FIELDS = [NAME_FIELD];`

Comment: that fixes the problem, only now it doesn't show me anything it just tells me [object Object]